# Install Visual Editor 1.5 under eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Tags: java, eclipse

When trying to install Visual Editor 1.5 on eclipse Helios I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Visual Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328 
(org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.5.0.R20101202-1328)
  Missing requirement: Visual Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328 
(org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.5.0.R20101202-1328) requires 
'org.eclipse.jem.proxy [2.0.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

I installed "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and trying to add this module on a clean installation with an empty workspace.
Which module contains org.eclipse.jem.proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it connecting the computer I was using to internet. I did so after getting bored of manually downloading every required module.